# Scrapy / xpath not working - only with css

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy

i try to scrape this site: https://www.magnatiles.com/products/page/1/

I get all the elements with:

```
products = response.xpath("//ul[@class='products']//ancestor::li")
```

No i try to find the price for all elements in the scrapy shell - at first i tried:

```
>>> for p in products:
...  p.xpath("//span[@class='price']//child::bdi/text()").get()           
... 
'134.99'
'134.99'
'134.99'
'134.99'
'134.99'
'134.99'
'134.99'
'134.99'
'134.99'
```

It seems that with that i only get the first entry altough i am using the loop

Then i tried it with css-selecting and it worked:

```
>>> for p in products:
...  p.css("span.price bdi::text").get()
... 
'134.99'
'49.99'
'39.99'
'39.99'
'39.99'
'129.99'
'24.99'
'49.99'
'119.99'
```

Why is this not working when i am using the xpath-selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After iterating to select xpath you have to use `.//` to get the desired result. Try as follows:

```
p.xpath(".//span[@class='price']//child::bdi/text()").get()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a xpath on already defined web element

then you can use

```
for p in products:
    p.xpath(".//span[@class='price']//child::bdi/text()").get()
```

Answer (score 1):

This xpath selector works in Chrome too.

```
//span[@class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"]//child::bdi/text()
```